# detecting if User pressed Go or hide keyboard button UITextField

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I am making a browser type app..

Now i have made the Url entering **textfield**...which shows up the keyboard..

Now i have made it be Url type keyboard..**it has Go button and for iPad a button to hide the keyboard..**

```
-(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
```

i know above is the method that is called when user clicks return on Keyboard..
but for iPad ..there are two different things..i want to go the new URL if user presses Go..and leave the window as it is if user presses hide keyboard..but the problem is both the events report

```
-(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
```

**so how do i differentiate user pressed Go ..or just hide keyboard..**

Comment: the hide keyboard button is the default bottom right button that is in keyboard of iPad

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently now it seems that the Go button only reports

```
-(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
```

and hide keyboard button doesn't..

I am pretty sure yesterday this was not the case..but anyways..i believe i am only to blame for this mess up..i will leave the question open if anyone needs clearing.

Comment: the hide button doesn't call this delegate, it never did

Answer (score 12):

When the user taps Hide button, the **UIKeyboardWillHideNotification** gets called,so you should register for observing it

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                     selector:@selector(keyboardWillHideHandler:)
                                         name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification
                                       object:nil];


- (void) keyboardWillHideHandler:(NSNotification *)notification {
    //show another viewcontroller here
}
```

Comment: so textfield should not `resignFirstresponder?`

Comment: this does not seem to solve my problem.. i think this notification will be called for both Go and hide keyboard button..so i still won't be able to distinguish if user clicked Go

Answer (score 0):

You try to use touch function with key board I think it will work.

Answer (score 0):

At least on iOS 12 [textFieldDidEndEditing(_:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextfielddelegate/1619591-textfielddidendediting) is called when tapping the hide button (on iPad).

Hope this helps.