# how to hide keyboard on ipad while pressing arrowkey

Tags: iphone, ipad, keyboard

In iPad we have

```
  - (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{

[textFieldOne resignFirstResponder];
[textFieldTwo resignFirstResponder];
return YES;


}
```

but also we can close keyboard on arrow key so whcich that method of arrow key on which we can show something

here is the screenshot

[image]

Comment: Arrow keys on iPad ? I don't quite get it.

Comment: I think you can find what you want here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10151426/detecting-if-user-pressed-go-or-hide-keyboard-button-uitextfield

Comment: please show me that **arrow key**..screenshot

Comment: you can see on ipadpeek bottom key on righ hand  http://ipadpeek.com/

Comment: @MilKyWaY did you see that arrow key

Comment: they key is beside ?123 on right hand side

Comment: @MilKyWaY can you help me out now in this

Comment: dude,I'm willing to help..but after reading your question I can't yet figure out what your question is..make it more clear!!

Comment: refer Cocoa Event Handling Guide : https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/EventOverview/HandlingKeyEvents/HandlingKeyEvents.html

Comment: you want to say that your keyboard hide key isn't working at all right?

Comment: it is working as we have resign first responder event what event we can call on that key which i am mentionong

Answer (score 0):

There isn't any function which gets called when "Hide Keyboard" button is clicked on iPad. If you want to perform any action when keyboard goes down. You can either use following function :

```
- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
```

Or, you can use keyboard notifications i.e. `UIKeyboardWillHideNotification`.